# How can I disable the ripple effect for the accordition list from React Native Paper?

Tags: reactjs, list, react-native, button

So, here is my code:

```
<List.Section style={styles.listSectionStyle}>
                    <List.Accordion
                        title="Language"
                        titleStyle={styles.activeListText}
                    >
                        <List.Item
                            title="Русский"
                            titleStyle={styles.activeListText}
                            style={styles.otherListElements}
                        />
                        <List.Item
                            title="English"
                            titleStyle={styles.inactiveListText}
                            style={styles.otherListElements}
                        />
                        <List.Item
                            title="Español"
                            titleStyle={styles.inactiveListText}
                            style={styles.otherListElements}
                        />
                        <List.Item
                            title="Deutsch"
                            titleStyle={styles.inactiveListText}
                            style={styles.bottomListElement}
                        />
                    </List.Accordion>
                </List.Section>
```

I have the ripple effect while pressing the list. I don't need it, so is it possible to disable it in React Native Paper?

Answer (score 0):

Anybody still wants the solution to this problem?
So, what I did was edit the .tsx file and change the touchable ripple component to a component of my choice.
Open the node_modules folder in your project directory and find the react native package.
Inside that go to `src/component/list` open the `ListAccordion.tsx` file.
Inside that file the easiest way to find what you're looking for is to search for  *TouchableRipple* and you'll find a *TouchableRipple* component, wrapping some other components. Change that to any component of your choice. In my case I imported Touchable opacity from react native, replaced the Touchable Ripple element with it, and set active opacity to 1. Note: you cannot use a **View** because view doesn't have OnPress prop. Save the file and that should solve it.

Comment: Please be aware that modifications to code in `node_modules` will be lost as soon as the package is updated or you install the project on another computer. There are multiple ways to do this. One is to fork the project on GitHub and use this fork instead of the official package.